# who has a whole cassandra jdbc example which can run in eclipse?

Tags: cassandra

the example may include:

create keyspace and columnfamily

insert data

select/get data and show in Console

because I found this http://cassandra.apache.org/doc/cql/CQL.html is hard to me

Comment: I also need a FILE-read-write example of cassandra (may be using datastax?) thank you！

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thank you for attention , I got it http://niranjandubey.blogspot.com/2012/11/cassandra-jdbc-to-perform-crud.html.

But I also need a FILE-read-write example of cassandra (may be using datastax?)